# org.neo4j.cypher.internal.parser.v1_9.CypherParserImpl.parse (neo4j url parsing exception)

Tags: java, parsing, neo4j, cypher

I create node in `neo4j` which contains URL-s.

```
          node.setProperty("subject","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#Melinda_Gates");
```

QUERY:

```
 String subject = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#Melinda_Gates"
 String query = "start n=node(*) where n.subject ?= " + subject
            + " return n";
 ExecutionResult rs = e.execute(query);
```

EXCEPTION:

> at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.parser.v1_9.CypherParserImpl.parse(CypherParserImpl.scala:47)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.CypherParser.parse(CypherParser.scala:44)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$prepare$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:80)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$prepare$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:80)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.LRUCache.getOrElseUpdate(LRUCache.scala:37)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.prepare(ExecutionEngine.scala:80)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:72)
>       at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:67)

Comment: I can guess what your question is but it might be useful if you explicitly ask it of everyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cypher syntax for regular expressions uses `=~`, not `?=`. Also, the regular expression must match the entire string.

So, if you are looking for a way to find out if `n.subject` contains the value of your `subject` variable, this might work for you:

```
 String query = "start n=node(*) where n.subject =~ '.*" + subject + ".*' return n";
```

Or, starting with neo4j 2.3, you can use this simpler query:

```
 String query = "start n=node(*) where n.subject CONTAINS '" + subject + "' return n";
```